# Swift: iOS: Calling a segue from inside a container view

Tags: swift

*Edited Reason: Easier to understand*
[image]

- UIViewController #1

  - Button #2 (Bar Button Item)
  - Container View

    - Button #1
- UIViewController #2 (Profile)

Lets say my main function for the segue is this:

```
func showProfile(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toViewProfile", sender: self)
}
```

When button 2 is pressed:

```
@IBAction func btnProfilePressed(sender: AnyObject){
    showProfile()
}
```

And when button 1 is pressed from the UIView inside the Container View:

```
UIViewControllerClassName().showProfile()
```

The **button#2 works** but **button#1 doesn't** and produces this error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentnException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'toViewProfile'**

Question: How can I get button #1 working properly?

*Side note: I think that when button #1 is being pressed, it's most likely trying to show the UIViewController#2 inside the ContainerView.*

Comment: Can you post your project somewhere?

Comment: I cannot, sorry. Boss' orders ;)

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571139/how-to-perform-segue-from-container-view-within-a-view-displayed-by-navigation-c

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom segue, add a "regular" **show segue** from UIViewController1 to UIViewController2. Give this segue the identifier `MyCustomSegue`. You can do this by selecting the segue in the Interface Builder and open the attribute inspector.

[image]

Comment: What I found in another thread here is the following: 

Delete the app in the simulator (under iOS Simulator - reset content and settings) or remove the app on your iPhone. Clean and re-run.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but that wasn't it either. I think that when button #1 is being pressed, it's most likely trying to show the UIViewController#2 inside the ContainerView. That's my only guess. I just don't know how to fix it.