# How to perform segue from container view within a view displayed by navigation controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image: Storyboard]

I want to segue from a view container within "H" that is presented using the navigation controller connected to the Split View Controller. How can I accomplish this? I have tried regular performSegueWithIdentifier using locally linked storyboard ID's but that removes the top navigation bar. I want to retain the top navigation bar and execute the segue as if it was done using the master navigation controller (rows that select which view controller is being presented in the detail view).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example of how to perform a segue from an embedded ViewController.

[image: Sample Storyboard]

---

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol SegueHandler: class {
    func segueToNext(identifier: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, SegueHandler {

    func segueToNext(identifier: String) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "EmbedH" {
            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! HViewController
            dvc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

---

**HViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class HViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: SegueHandler?

    @IBAction func pressH(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.segueToNext("GoToGreen")
    }

}
```

---

**Setup:**

1. Use delegation to have the `HViewController` tell its embedding viewController to perform the segue.
2. Create a protocol called `SegueHandler` which just describes a class that implements the method `segueToNext(identifier: String)`.

   ```
   protocol SegueHandler: class {
       func segueToNext(identifier: String)
   }
   ```
3. Make your viewController implement this protocol by adding it to the `class` declaration line:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, SegueHandler {
   ```

   and by implementing the required function.
4. Add a `delegate` property to `HViewController`:

   ```
   weak var delegate: SegueHandler?
   ```
5. Click on the embed segue arrow between ViewController and HViewController.  Give it the identifier `"EmbedH"` in the *Attributes Inspector*.
6. Create a *show* segue between ViewController and the GreenViewController by <kbd>Control</kbd> dragging from the viewController icon at the top of ViewController to the GreenViewController.  Name this segue `"GoToGreen"` in the *Attributes Inspector*.
7. In `prepareForSegue` for ViewController, when the `"EmbedH"` segue happens, set the `delegate` property of `HViewController` to `self` (ViewController).
8. When the user clicks the `H` button in the `HViewController`, call `delegate?.segueToNext("GoToGreen")` to trigger the segue in ViewController.

---

Here it is running in the simulator:

[image: Simulator Demonstration]

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the detailed response. :) I will try to implement this later today and see whether I can get it to work in my test app.

I got the intended behavior, btw, by adding Show Detail Segues in the appropriate storyboards. Then, when I call "self.performSegueWithIdentifier" it keeps the navigation bar and the buttons function as intended (keep history of views, etc.). Is there anything wrong with doing it this way?

Comment: I'm not clear on how exactly you did it.  If what you did works, add it as an answer as well (you're allowed to answer your own question on Stack Overflow).  Be specific in your answer how you set up the segues and how you are calling them and from where.

Comment: So my method destroys/instantiates a new view controller every time it is called from the master navigation controller (instead of within the main app VC). This isn't good because I want to maintain any user changes in data there. I tried implementing your method, but when I click a button it just sits there. Neither the "prepareForSegue" nor "segueToNext" gets called. The equivalent of "HViewController" is inside the "H" storyboard reference on the picture I uploaded earlier.

Comment: Make sure you set the delegate pointer.  If `delegate` is `nil`, nothing will happen.  Are you seeing the `Embed` segue happening in `prepareForSegue` ?  This should be in the `prepareForSegue` of your `Menu` controller.

Comment: This is my set-up right now: MenuVC (segueToNext func, and prepare func override) -> Storyboard Reference (H) and then within H storyboard I have an embedded container within a regular VC. Within the embedded container I call "self.delegate?.segueToNext but nothing happens.

Comment: Time to debug.  Put prints at each stage, or set breakpoints.  Make sure everything is happening as you expect.

Comment: Is it a problem that I have my flow of events like this? MenuVC -> Home Storyboard Reference -> Home VC -> Child VC. So basically, I am asking Child VC to perform a segue as if it was done by MenuVC.

Comment: Also, if you want to present the save viewController each time instead of creating a new one, then you can't use a segue to present it.  Segues always create a new instance.  Instead, you should instantiate the viewController yourself with `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID")` and then present it with `self.presentViewController`.

Comment: let vc:FormViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "SplitUI", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitMenu") as! FormViewController
                        vc.self.performSegueWithIdentifier("navTest", sender: self) I have tried this code without any luck. It also does nothing. I feel like there might be a deeper issue here although the segue ID's are all set-up properly and nothing errors out.

Comment: Appreciate! Saved a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

I was needing exactly what @vacawama proposed here, though I couldn't reproduce that, I tried exactly your steps but `self.delegate?.segueToNext("GoToGreen")` got called but neither the protocol itself nor the container view controller. After an entire day searching about this approach I realized the problem was with the swift version. Just replace this:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EmbedH" {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! HViewController
        dvc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

for this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EmbedH" {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! HViewController
        dvc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Other detail I was missing was about the embedded segue. Be sure to connect the container View to the HViewController, not the View Controller itself, otherwise the Embed option for segue won't appear.